# Hibernate JPA - PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, read the locked record

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, locking, pessimistic-locking

I was reading this article https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking, where it's written that

> PESSIMISTIC_WRITE – allows us to obtain an exclusive lock and prevent the data from being read, updated, or deleted

So I tried to confirm this.

In Transaction(TX1), I took a **PESSIMISTIC_WRITE** lock on an **entity1**. Then called a **Thread.sleep(5)**.
While TX1 is going on, I did a **GET API** call on the same **entity1**, which returned the data with 200 status. After which TX1 got completed.
Maybe my implementation is wrong here, Could anyone help me in understanding this?

Resources used: JAVA 8, Mysql version: 5.6.34, Engine: InnoDB

If I'm able to read a locked entity, then this may lead to a dirty update.
So in TX2, I did a plain findById and then did an update on entity1. Here TX2 is waiting till TX1 is completed because of locking but TX2 will do a dirty update as it is not aware of the changes made by TX1.